# AVAudioPlayer play sound async not working

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I want completely load sound from url, and then play it:

I'm using [Heneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) library for cache result.

```
if let soundUrl = URL(string: "http://wow.zamimg.com/hearthhead/sounds/ruru/VO_NEW1_010_Play_01.mp3") {
                Shared.dataCache.fetch(URL: soundUrl).onSuccess { soundData in

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        do {
                            var audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData)
                            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
                            audioPlayer.play()
                        } catch  let error as NSError {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

`audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()` - returns `true`

`soundData` - is not `nil`

Comment: Why do you want to use cache? Is it in order to buffer the streaming or for different purposes not related to the player?

Comment: i want to cache sound. For example if it is long song, i want to download it first and then play. because user can play it a lot of times

Comment: Downloading the full song makes no sense to me. What  you should is buffer the data so that you can ensure the playing will never stop and if it does for a network failure or something handle the stall so that it resumes the playing right after the network is recovered. Also if it is a long song user can play it many times.